# How to find the first entry of the keyword on the page and select it using Selenium via C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

i need to find the first entry of selecting keyword on the page and select it. Double click on this word i guess. I tried this with xpath but i think it might be something wrong.

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//span[contains(text(),'"+word+"')]");
```

Comment: show `HTML` for target `<span>` element

Comment: what you mean by saying "first entry of selecting keyword" ?

Comment: For example i need to find first entry of "stackoverlow" on this page and select it.

Comment: Try `//span[text()[contains(.,'" + word + "')]]`. Also, you can text the xpath in chrome console using `$x("your xpath")`